# Could propellers benefit from the design of the Blue Edge rotor?

Tags: propeller, noise

[image]
Source: [wired.com](https://www.wired.com/2010/02/eurocopter-moves-one-step-closer-to-whisper-mode/)

If indeed the [Blue Edge blades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Edge) reduce noise by 50%, could the similar design be used on [forward-facing] propellers without a penalty in speed or agility?

Comment: It would help if you cited your sources here, what blue edge blades are you referring to?

Comment: That wiki page linked in the description is the saddest stub I've ever seen. The page on the [Airbus H160](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_Helicopters_H160) gives more info on the rotor design. This does seem to be progressing pretty slowly, given the original announcement for the blade design was a decade ago. There's also a [fairly recent paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/331593952_From_ERATO_Basic_Research_to_the_Blue_Edge_TM_Rotor_Blade)